# Como serializar uma classe para arquivo em C#?

Tags: c#, serialização

Como faço para serializar uma classe para um arquivo em C#?

Tenho uma classe

```
[Serializable]
public class MyClass {
     public int MyNumber { get; set; }
     public string MyName { get; set; }


}
```

Comment: Em que formato? Em que parte tens dúvidas - na serialização, ou na gravação para o disco?

Comment: Queria um método para exportar para xml mesmo

Comment: Existem muitas páginas no MSDN acerca de serialização para XML. Uma simples pesquisa no google devolve uma lista de documentação oficial. Porque não começar por aí?

Comment: Cheguei a ver com Stream, mas queria um método direto, se existir

Comment: Afinal a dúvida está na serialização ou na gravação? Primeiro disseste que querias exportar para XML, agora estás a falar em Streams que são usadas para gravar em disco. Tens de ser mais específico.

Comment: Quero serializar para arquivo, ou seja para gravar em disco. Estou fazendo uma integração e vou precisar salvar o objeto em disco para que outro sistema o leia.

Comment: Consegui encontrar esta solução com stream.  public static void WriteFile(object obj, string filename)
        {
            byte[] data;
            using (MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

                formatter.Serialize(mStream, obj);
                data = mStream.GetBuffer();
            }

            File.WriteAllBytes(filename, data);
        }

Answer (score 1):

Você pode implementar um métodos que recebe uma entidade genérica e realiza a Serialização.

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Serializes an object to an XML/Extensible Markup Language string.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">The type of the object to serialize.</typeparam>
        /// <param name="value">The object to serialize.</param>
        /// <param name="serializedXml">Filled with a string that is the XmlSerialized object.</param>
        /// <param name="throwExceptions">If true, will throw exceptions. Otherwise, returns false on failures.</param>
        /// <returns>A boolean value indicating success.</returns>
        public static bool Serialize<T>(T value, ref string serializedXml, bool throwExceptions = false)
        {
        #if DEBUG
        #warning When in DEBUG Mode XML Serialization Exceptions will be      thrown regardless of throwExceptions paramter.
            throwExceptions = true;
        #endif

            if (value == null)
                if (throwExceptions)
                    throw new ArgumentNullException("The value is expected to be a non-null object.");
                else
                    return false;

            try
            {
                XmlSerializer xmlserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

                using (StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter())
                using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter))
                {
                    xmlserializer.Serialize(writer, value);

                    serializedXml = stringWriter.ToString();

                    return true;
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                if (throwExceptions)
                    throw;

                return false;
            }
        }
```

Segue link com a solução completa :

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/100930/xml-serialization-helper-class

Answer (score 1):

você pode implementar usando DataContract:

Sua class com os atributos `DataMember` e `DataContract`

```
[DataContract]
public class MyClass 
{
    [DataMember]
    public int MyNumber { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string MyName { get; set; }
}
```

métodos extensivos para converter de objeto para uma string xml e virse-versa.

```
public static class SerializeXMLUtils
{
    public static string serializeObjectToXmlString<T>(this T objectToSerialize)
    {
        var xmlString = string.Empty;
        using(var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
            serializer.WriteObject(memoryStream, objectToSerialize);
            memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            using(var streamReader = new StreamReader(memoryStream))
            {
                xmlString = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                streamReader.Close();
            }
            memoryStream.Close();
        }
        return xmlString;
    }

    public static T deserializeXmlStringToObject<T>(this string xmlString)
    {
        var deserializedObject = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
        using(var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var xmlBinary = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xmlString);
            memoryStream.Write(xmlBinary, 0, xmlBinary.Length);
            memoryStream.Position = 0;

            var deserializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
            deserializedObject = deserializer.ReadObject(memoryStream);
            memoryStream.close();
        }
        return deserializedObject;
    }

    public static void serializeObjectToFile<T>(this T objectToSerialize, string fileName)
    {
        using(var fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create))
        {
            var serializer = new DataContractSerializer<T>();
            serializer.WriteObject(fileStream, objectToSerialize);
            fileStream.Close();
        }
    }

    public static T deserializeFileToObject<T>(this string fileName)
    {
        var deserializedObject = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
        using(var fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open))
        {
            var deserializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
            using (var xmlReader = XmlDictionaryReader.CreateTextReader(fileStream, new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas()))
            {
                deserializedObject = deserializer.ReadObject(xmlReader, true);
                xmlReader.Close();
            }
            fileStream.Close();
        }
        return deserializedObject;
    }
}
```

uma vez que tenha os metodos extensivos prontos, basta chama-los da seguinte forma:

```
//serializando
myObject.serializeObjectToFile<MyClass>(fileName);
//deserializando
var myObject = fileName.deserializeFileToObject<MyClass>();
```

caso precise serializar para um arquivo, basta substituir o MemoryStream por um FileStream.

Como está usando DataContract, você tambem pode serializar para JSON usando [Json.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/), assim como as suas classes já estarão prontas para expor atraves de um webservice (preferencialmente WCF).

Answer (score 0):

Entonrei esta solução

```
public static void WriteFile(object obj, string filename)
{
    byte[] data;
    using (MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

        formatter.Serialize(mStream, obj);
        data = mStream.GetBuffer();
     }

     File.WriteAllBytes(filename, data);
}
```

Comment: Isso serializa para um formato binário, não para XML.

Comment: Realmente não resolveu. Vou tentar com XmlSerializer que li no MSDN.